# Writing sequences into separate list or array

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to extracts these sequences into separate lists or arrays in Python from a file.

My data looks like:

```
>gene_FST
AGTGGGTAATG--TGATG...GAAATTTG
>gene_FPY
AGT-GG..ATGAAT---AAATGAAAT--G
```

I would like to have

```
seq1 = [AGTGGGTAATG--TGATG...GAAATTTG]
seq2 = [AGT-GG..ATGAAT---AAATGAAAT--G]
```

My plan is to later compare the contents of the list

I would appreciate any advise

Comment: Is the data coming from a file?  Please provide a [mcve] of what you are facing

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

So far, here's what I have done, that

```html
f = open (r"C:\Users\Olukayode\Desktop\my_file.txt", 'r') #first r - before the normal string it converts normal string to raw string
def parse_fasta(lines):
    seq = []
    seq1 = []
    seq2 = []
    head = []
    data = ''
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if data:
                seq.append(data)
                data = ''
            head.append(line[1:])
        else:
            data+= line.rstrip()
    seq.append(data)
    return seq

    
h = parse_fasta(f)
print(h)
print(h[0])
print(h[1])
```

gives:

```
['AGTGGGTAATG--TGATG...GAAATTTG', 'AGT-GG..ATGAAT---AAATGAAAT--G']
AGTGGGTAATG--TGATG...GAAATTTG
AGT-GG..ATGAAT---AAATGAAAT--G
```

I think I just figured it out, I can pass each string the list containing both sequences into a separate list, if possible though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the exact results you were looking for in your original question, i.e.

```
seq1 = [AGTGGGTAATG--TGATG...GAAATTTG]
seq2 = [AGT-GG..ATGAAT---AAATGAAAT--G]
```

you can do it in a variety of ways.  Instead of changing anything you already have though, you can just convert your data into a dictionary and print the dictionary items.

```
your code block...
h = parse_fasta(f)

sDict = {}
for i in range(len(h)):
    sDict["seq"+str(i+1)] = [h[i]]

for seq, data in sDict.items():
    print(seq, "=", data)
```